# C# Compiler (csc.exe) exits with code 1 (MSB6006)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, msbuild, mono, visual-studio-mac

I'm working in a Xamarin.Forms-based project in VS Mac, and as of the recent days I had no build errors. Suddenly, after creating a simple interface+class with only a couple of members and methods, I'm starting to get this build error:

> "csc.exe" exited with code 1. (MSB6006)

I have so far tried deleting the new files, clean/rebuild, switched back to *mcs* and *xbuild* in case there was a problem with *csc* and *msbuild*, done fresh installs of *mono 5.4.1* and VS Mac, tried reverting to *mono 4.8* (pre-csc and msbuild), deleted obj/bin folders and refactored all of my async partial methods but to no success. There seems to be little information elsewhere on the internet as well.

The error itself happens on this line in **Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5)**:

```
<Csc Condition="'%(_CoreCompileResourceInputs.WithCulture)' != 'true'"
```

Any help or insight on the problem would be much appreciated!

Additional technical information if for any help:

- VS Mac v7.3.3 (build 7) - same version as before build error
- Target framework .NET Standard v2.0
- .NET SDK v2.1.4
- Xamarin.Forms v2.5.0.121934
- Recently converted from PCL to .NET Standard

Comment: I would try enabling diagnostic output from msbuild (preferences - Projects - Build - Log Verbosity) to see if more information is output. Also try building from the command line with msbuild. If it fails from the command line you can also enable verbose output using `/v:diag` and output it to a file using `msbuild YourSolution.sln /v:diag > build.log`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MattWard! I tried building from the command line to no success, so I guess VS itself can't be blamed, and it seems to be something in my shared code project. I forgot to mention I had set the log verbosity to *diagnostic*, but the build log didn't provide any more information than VS. Looks like I'm going to have to look trough this more thoroughly.

Comment: In that case I would copy the full csc command line from the msbuild output and try running that on its own from the command line. That might give you more information.

Comment: Thanks, @MattWard! I got an extra line stating there was another error which seemed to be of no importance to VS or msbuild. The error "CS1002" referred to one of the files I removed earlier, so it seems that VS didn't delete all the references to the file (removed it from project, didn't delete it from system) so it was included in the build task. Removed the file entirely, and now it builds!